# Most Efficient ERPNext Installation Method

Tags: open-source, erp, erpnext

I'm taking on the challenge of trying to test and develop with ERPNext. I'm new to ERPNext, Docker, Compose, Git, etc. I'm going to need to learn these from scratch.

What is the general most efficient way to install ERPNext (for testing purposes for now) on either a Mac or Windows computer?

Below are my criteria:

- I need to be able to create backups and transfer them and implement
  them to a different computer if necessary.
- I'm also attempting to do this in as budget-friendly way as
  possible. I'm probably not going to be spending money on hosting or
  anything of the sort (completely free is the goal).
- ERPNext needs to be easily upgradeable/downgradeable to different versions
- The implementation of ERPNext will eventually need custom code/integrations

I've read that there are different methods of using ERPNext, depending on the OS, including VirtualBox, and Windows Subsystem for Linux. I'm looking for the fastest, least resource-hungry, and most versatile solution

I will check out the official ERPNext documentation, but I would also like to know other people's personal experiences and methods.

This is a big task to take on, so I'm looking for some advice before delving into this.

Comment: @LaxmanTandon, thanks for the suggestion. For now, I'm trying to implement this locally without spending any money and may consider a cloud option in the future.

Comment: I've started with VirtualBox. I've installed Ubuntu Desktop. Tried to install ERPNext. Failed many times. Then somehow it worked. Now, I am windows-free. I use Zorin OS and for ERPNext I use LXC containers.

Comment: @TurkerTunali, I have just heard about LXC for the first time from you. Can this be used on a Windows or Mac computer without the use of VirtualBox? I would prefer to avoid an extra layer or emulation that might slow down ERPNext or use more resources.

Comment: @n00b Frappe Cloud has free trial period. If you are evaluating ERPNext and if you need a faster setup, Frappe Cloud is better choice.

Comment: @ChillarAnand, I generally avoid free trials and would still like to start locally.

Answer (score 4):

You can use frappe_docker setup to quickly get the environment up and running.

https://github.com/frappe/frappe_docker

If you want least resource hungry option, you can setup a site using bench.

https://github.com/frappe/bench

Comment: Thanks, I would ideally like to use a minimally resource-hungry option, but I would also like to make sure that whatever installation I create, can be migrated to another computer with a different OS, so compatibility is also very important.